# How to check if an object has a uvmap with python?

Tags: python, uv

How would I test if an object object has a uv map from Python?

Run some code in this case, otherwise throw an error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case you'll need to check if the objects mesh data has any UV layers.
This works for vertex colors too.

```
import bpy
if bpy.context.object.data.uv_layers:
    print("We have UV's")
else:
    # if this runs from an operator, you may want to report an error instead.
    raise Exception("Missing UV's")
```

Where `uv_layers` can be replaced by `vertex_colors`, `materials`... or any other sequence you want to check is empty or not.

Note: In Python you could check: `if len(bpy.context.object.data.uv_layers) > 0:` however there is no need, since all sequences will evaluate to `False` when empty, infact, this is slower in some cases since counting all items can be avoided when we only need to check if its empty.

Comment: but how to check if the actual uvmap has any image assigned to it and select only those objects? you see: I do LEGO models in Blender and all the bricks (objects) has uvmap, but only some of them have actual image assigned to it, and I need to select all from the bunch (it can be hundreds of them!) that do not have any image in uvmap (that is: having empty uvmap) - can it be done?